# Problem with IE7 JQuery, Ajax and CSS

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

In a simple web page I load some new HTML into a **div** using *load(url)*
Works fine in most browsers but, surprise, surprise, IE7 behaves differently.
All the other browsers apply the pages CSS styles to the newly loaded HTML but IE7 doesn't.

Any ideas?

Ken

---

**Update**
The new HTML is just a code fragment, e.g.

```
<div class="classname">
blah blah blah
</div>
```

---

**Update** I think I'm calling it OK.
This isn't what I'm actually doing but a simplified version which reproduces the problem ...

```
.
.
.    
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2"); 
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#nav-home").click(function() {
           $("#girc-content").load("home.html");
         });
.
.
.
```

**Update** On further investigation the problem appears to be slightly more odd than I thought.

I tried Steerpike's suggestion because I originally thought the problem was that the CSS styles were not being applied.

However, it now appears that only some of the styles are being applied.
For example, the text color attribute for the `<h2>` tag is applied, but the width attribute for the `<div>` tag is not.

Comment: Are you loading HTML chunk from the same domain?

Comment: Can you post a cutdown jquery fragment?

Comment: You wanna hear something scary?  After 8 minutes, this question already shows up in a Google search...

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem using your supplied code. Using your javascript to load my test content has IE7 (actually IE8 in 7 mode) apply the CSS styles I gave it without issue. There must be something about the HTML you're trying to load or maybe your CSS rules?

Comment: And yeah, cletus, that *is* pretty insane, although I guess when I think about it not hugely surprising - I imagine google recognises how good the content is here generally and how rapidly it changes, makes sense they'd spider it with alarming regularity :)

Comment: Jeff has commented in the SO blog or codinghorror (can't remember whcih) that ***70%*** of the site's traffic is google crawling.

Comment: Having more of the actual semantic markup and specific css rules used would likely help if you're still having trouble finding the solution, kenneedham

Comment: I'm creating a small example which exhibits the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of extra information, take 2...

Are the styles not being applied in the master HTML page or the page you're loading?  If they're in the page you're loading it seems that IE strips out script and style tags from XMLHttpRequest objects.

Given that it's not that and I'm intrigued I constructed a sample:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#girc-content { border: 1px solid black; width: 100px }
h3 { color: red; }
</style>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2"); 
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav-home").click(function() {
      $("#girc-content").load("test2.html");
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="girc-content">
blah blah blah
</div>
<input type="button" value="click me" id="nav-home">
</body>
</html>
```

and test2.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h3>This is a test</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly for me in IE8 standards and compatibility mode (sorry no IE7 any more).

I did notice when I copied your google onload snippet that you were missing some closing braces/parentheses. Was this just a cut and paste error or a problem with your Javascript?  It might explain the inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: I only reference the external style sheet in the static part of my page. The HTML which is loaded dynamically has no such references but uses the styles defined in the static portion. There is no script in the dynamic portion.

Comment: You can revert IE8 back to 7 by using Tools > Developer Tools > Browser Mode > Internet Explorer 7. The IE team says that the mode is functionally identical to actual IE7, but apparently there are slight discrepencies.

Comment: Ah I knew I'd heard about that somewhere. Tried that, same deal. works fine.

Comment: I modified that code sample to look more like what I have and it still works in IE7.
Which, I think, means there is something wrong with my CSS template.
I should have thought of that earlier.
The fact that the <h2> tage works but the <div> ones don't should have been a clue.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Found it.
I had a border="0"; in one of the styles
The other browsers didn't seem to mind but IE just stopped applying any styles after that point.

I'll give you the TICK as your questions prompted me to look in the right place.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Try '*touching*' the content again after you load it. The simplest way tends to just add a null string to the innerHTML

```
$("#nav-home").click(function() {
    $("#girc-content").load("home.html");
    $("#girc-content")[0].innerHTML += '';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The link helped me; essentially, adding the style tag into the head, even dynamically, applies the styles through ie. I added this to the top of the onready handler and it worked well.

http://topsecretproject.finitestatemachine.com/2009/09/how-to-load-javascript-and-css-dynamically-with-jquery/

```
$("head").append("<link>");
css = $("head").children(":last");
css.attr({
  rel:  "stylesheet",
  type: "text/css",
  href: "/javascripts/jwysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.css"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem - IE8 sometimes has a problem with apply styles in content loaded by ajax jQuery function. I don't know why but this helped:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'content.html',
success: function(data) {
   $('#content').html(data); //styles doeas not appear in ie8
   document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data; /* ie8 - now it works oO */
}
```

Comment: I might know why, because innerHTML will force browser to render DOM again.