# IE7 and display of a navigation element

Tags: internet-explorer-7, slider

I recently added a Jquery slider to a website, and it works fine in the browsers I've tried, except for IE7.  However, IE7 traffic makes up 25% of our daily visitors, so I'd like to correct it, if possible.

The problem is the alignment of an unordered list. I just can't figure out how to make it work properly.

Website in question is http://www.pnac.org/ The problem is the dot navigation under the slider.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with [www.tykeknit.com](http://www.tykeknit.com) (we're probably using the same jquery plugin), and the information I found on stackoverflow ([stackoverflow.com/questions/689260/problem-with-ie7-jquery-ajax-and-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689260/problem-with-ie7-jquery-ajax-and-css)) was that IE7's script engine cannot handle it, and strips it bare… Hope that helps :s

btw, your site looks very nice.